# Use of unsafePerformIO in programming language interpreter runtime

Tags: haskell, io, referential-transparency

To add IO functions to a programming language interpreter written in Haskell, I have basically two options:

- Modify the entire interpreter to run inside the IO monad
- Have the runtime functions that can be invoked by interpreted programs use `unsafePerformIO`.

The former feels like a bad idea to me -- this effectively negates *any*  purity benefits by having `IO` reach practically everywhere in the program.  I also currently use `ST` heavily, and would have to modify large quantities of the program to achieve this, as there is no way I can see to use both `ST` and `IO` at the same time (?).

The latter makes me nervous -- as the function name states, it *is* unsafe, but I think in this situation it may be justified.  Particularly:

- The amount of code touched by this change would be very small.
- The points at which IO may be performed are explicitly sequenced already by the use of `seq` at control points during evaluation of interpreted expressions.
- Perhaps more importantly, values returned by IO actions would only be used within interpreted sections of code, where I can guarantee referential transparency by the fact that the interpreter cannot be called multiple times with the same arguments, as an operation counter will be threaded through the entire system as part of the same change, and is *always* passed with a unique value to every function that would use `unsafePerformIO`.

In this circumstance, is there a good reason not to use `unsafePerformIO`?

### Update

I was asked why I want to retain purity in the interpreter.  There are a number of reasons, but perhaps the most pressing is that I intend to later build a compiler for this language, and the language will include a variety of metaprogramming techniques that will require the compiler to include the interpreter, but I want to be able to guarantee purity of the results of compilation.  The language will have a pure subset for this purpose, and I would like the interpreter to be pure when executing that subset.

Comment: assuming your interpreter will interact with the user - wouldn't it run in IO anyway? Why not just wrap `IO` in values in the representation of your interpreted language as well?

Comment: What @Carsten said. If you are already manipulating values of different types, then perhaps one of those types could hold an IO value.

Comment: This *is* how I intend to model user interaction, as well as other forms of IO.  At present, IO is involved *only* during the initial module loading phase (which happens and is completed prior to execution).  At this point, it seems like the change to use IO during interpretation as well would lose at least some of the benefits of working in a pure system.  Avoiding IO when I don't need it seems like a useful goal, and if I can separate out a subsystem that *does* need it and *prove* that that subsystem is still referentially transparent, is there a good reason not to do so?

Comment: Predicting when exactly thunks are forced in a lazy language can be very tricky -- this is why there are virtually no lazy impure functional languages. Adding `seq`s at the right spots might be less trivial than it looks. Further -- could you write a mock type for the interpreter? Is it `int :: Program -> Result` or something similar?

Comment: The overall type of the interpreter is essentially `Scope s -> Expr -> ST s (Either ErrorMessage Value)`, where `Scope s` contains a description of both global (mutable) variables and functions/classes defined in the program, and the `Expr` is basically a simple bootstrap expression that calls a function in the program.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, you want to add `IO` actions to interpreted language (impure primops), while the interpreter itself is pure.

The first option is abstract primops from interpreter. For example, the interpreter could run in some unspecified monad, while priops are injected:

```
data Primops m = Primops
  { putChar :: Char -> m ()
  , getChar :: m Char
  , ...
  }

interpret :: Monad m => Primops m -> Program -> m ()
```

Now interpreter can't perform any `IO` action except the closed list of primops. (You can achieve similar result using custom monad instead of passing primops as an argument.)

But I'd consider it over-engineering until you say exactly why you need pure interpreter. Probably you don't? If you just want to make pure parts of the interpreter easy to test, then it is probably better to extract those parts into separate pure functions. That way the top level entry point will be impure, but small, yet all the interpreter's logic will be testable.

Comment: This is an option I thought about briefly, but figured would be too complex.  That said, it's probably worth considering a little longer, if only because it has some useful applications (e.g. recording a trace of IO operations so that programs can be tested more easily).  As to the *reason* I want a pure interpreter, I'll add an edit to the question.

Comment: OK, you need different sets of primops, so injecting them looks reasonable. Anyway, don't let overthinking prevent you from trying -- you'll probably redesign and refactor everything a number of times anyway.